# Time taken to break cryptographic key

Tags: key-generation

Assume it takes 512 clock cycles to check if a 64 cryptographic bit key is correct. Given a 64 bit plain text and its ciphertext, how long does it take to check all keys using a single core of a 4 GHz processor?

What is the time taken if it is done using a cluster of 1024 servers, each with a quad core processor?

I need help to understand if my approach is correct.

Number of keys tested in 1 second (using a single core): $\quad 2^2 \cdot 2^{30} / 2^9 = 2^{23}$ keys are tested.

Amount of time taken for a 64 bit key: $\quad 2^{64} / 2^{23} = 2^{41}$.

Using a cluster of 1024 servers:

Number of keys tested in 1 second: $\quad 2^2 \cdot 2^2 \cdot 2^{30} \cdot 2^{10} / 2^9 = 2^{35}$.

Total time taken: $\quad2^{64}/2^{35} = 2^{29}$

Comment: That sounds like you homework, doesn't it?

Comment: The numbers of key tested in one second seems wrong. With a CPU of clock-frequency `4*10^9 Hz` with one key check needing 512 clock cycles, we have a key-cracking speed of `(4*10^9 / 512) Keys/sec`. To crack 2^64 keys, we need a time of `2^64 [Keys] / (4*10^9 / 512 [Keys per sec])` (unit: `keys / (keys/sec) = sec`). (That number is equal to 74873 years, yours would be 278922 years due setting the clock to 2^30 Hertz, which is 1.074 gigahertz). A gigahertz is `10^9 Hz` in SI units.

Comment: My bad i should have used 4*2^30 instead. would the calculation be right now along with the cluster part?

Comment: 4 Gigahertz is still not `4*2^30 Hz`, but `4*10^9 Hz`, in SI units. Giga is the true "1 billion" here. Unless you have an explicit redefinition order from your lecturer.

Comment: oh yes i understand it should be 4*10^9, but it's just for knowledge so i do not need the accurate result so i represented in powers of 2 for easy calculation

Comment: The difference between taking `giga = 1,000,000,000` and `giga = 1,073,741,824` can make quite the difference in the number of years that are there. Particularly here the difference between `69,731 years` and `74873 years`. For the next part: If the server has a 4-core 4GHz processor then we can deduce 4times the cracking speed of it. With that, multiplied by 1024 servers, you can compute the numbers of keys tested by `1024 * 4 cores * 4 GHz / 512 clock cycles`, and the total time taken as `2^64 / num_keys_per_sec`.